# Endpoint Injection with Apache Camel

Tags: java, dependency-injection, apache-camel

I use **Apache Camel** for a projet and I would like to use the **produce annotation** to send an object in a file.
First, is it possible ? Is there a better way ?

Secondly, I tried this snippet code:

```
public class MyProducer {

  private static final String MEDIA = "file:";

  private static final String PATH = "c:/directory";

  @Produce(uri = MEDIA + PATH)
  protected ProducerTemplate producer;

  public void publish(MyObject o) {
    producer.sendBody(o);
  }
}
```

When I call the publish methode the producer is not inject (null). Anybody have an idea ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how you create the MyProducer class. You have to define it inside a spring context as a spring bean to make the annotations work.

Comment: Ok, thanks ! But is there a solution to use it without Spring. Java 6 is able to do injection, isn't it ?

Comment: I'm not realy familiar with Spring do you have a sample of Spring context for my problem ? Thanx

Comment: Take a look at the camel-example-pojo-messaging from the camel distro. It shows how to use a spring context together with some camel annotations.